# 1 ArrayController, 2 collectionView with reverse order

Tags: ember.js

1 have 1 ArrayController and 2 CollectionView classes (not instances) sharing this ArrayController.
(contentBinding: sharedArrayController)

Both collectionView needs to display the same array content (with different rendering) BUT in the reverse order.

Render1CollectionView: obj1, obj2, obj3
Render2CollectionView: obj3, obj2, obj1

How to tell the CollectionView to iterate in a reverse order ?

Other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in another post ... and it works perfectly

```
reversedContent: function(){
      return this.get('content').toArray().reverse();
    }.property('content.@each').cacheable()
```

Comment: calling cacheable() is now useless since computed property are cached by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would define a computed propery in the controller, and relying on it in the view (or template)

```
YourApp.YourController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    reversedContent: function(){
       return this.reverse();
    }.property('@each')
})
```

Comment: Sorry but this solution does not work... (I have tried). But I found another solution posted bellow.

Comment: Wow, I was pretty sure you could direcly rely on the arraycontroller as proxy around the content. Anyway, thanks for the feedback, will try it in a fiddle to see what's going (just out of curiosity)